# How can I make a formula tied to a dropdown ignore a particular list item?

Tags: excel, text, formula, excel-2016

I am making a rota spreadsheet in Excel 2016 and would like a formula tied to a dropdown list to ignore an "Annual Leave" item in the list rather than do a calculation.

I have a drop down called "start time" and one called "finish time". So for example I choose a start time from `5:30am` and a finish time of `4:00pm`, the formula in the next cell is `=SUM(G7-H7)*-24`, so it would change from `0.00` to `10.50` to reflect the hours worked.

I would like to be able to add "annual Leave" to the drop down lists and have the formula ignore it completely, so that the formula would give `0:00`. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. You can look into SUMIF Function

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure how your dropdown is working with your formula, I'll provide a general answer that you should be able to adapt.

Replace your formula with an `=IF(condition,true,false)` statement.  For example, `=IF(G7<>1,SUM(G7-H7)*24,0)` would calculate your formula if `G7` doesn't equal 1, but return `0` if it does.  If you want to test `H7` as well, you can nest IF statements:

```
=IF(G7<>1,IF(H7<>1,SUM(G7-H7)*24,0),0)
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the reply. The formula does the calculation perfectly but still gives the VALUE error message when any text is entered into cells h7 or g7. I've been googling for an answer for a while but all I can find is to use the sum function which ignores text. This works fine with just  numbers but doesn't seem to like the *24 which converts the sum from numbers to hours. Thanks again, I'll keep on trying :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out!!

=IFERROR(SUM(G7-G8)*-24,0)

Now displays Zero when text (annual leave) is selected from the dropdown.